# Session start include

Tags: php, session

I am quite insecure about sessions. I am making a site where a user can login. All my pages, no matter if you are logged in or not, is calling a header.html. So on my `index.php`, which everybody can see I have the following code:

```
**index.php**
<?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['username'])) include('resources/auth/login.php');
            else exit( header('Location: home.php') );

                if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();

    if( isset( $_GET['todo'] ) && $_GET['todo'] == 'logout'){

        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        //echo 'You have been logged out!';
    }
?>

<?php include 'resources/includes/header.html';?>
<!-- A lot of code -->
<?php include 'resources/includes/footer.html';?>
```

The session code comes before my header, and I am redirected to `home.php`. Should I have that session code in my header instead?

**home.php**

```
<?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
    ?>
    <?php include 'resources/includes/header.html';?>
        <!-- A lot of code -->
    <?php include 'resources/includes/footer.html';?>
```

So I just thought of earlier today, that I am actually including a session in my body? Because in my header.html I do not have anything with sessions. So should I have the session in my header.html? And in case how can I do that the most smart way?

Comment: `if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();` should just be `session_start()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Should I add that to my header.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `session_start()` must always be run BEFORE you attempt to access any `$_SESSION` variables.

So the safest way to code it is to always add it just after your first `<?php` in the script.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if( !isset( $_SESSION['username'])) include('resources/auth/login.php');
```

And

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) 

        include 'resources/includes/header.html';

        include 'resources/includes/footer.html';
?>
```

Comment: THank you for your answer. Do you think I should add it to my header, or is it okay where the session is started now?

Comment: Its a good idea to have it in EVERY script even if it is not required, as this stops the session timing out. As your header is called `header.html` PHP code will not be run, so possibly it would be better to create a `header.php` and add it in there

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer. I understand it now. I think I will make an include 'session.php' then.